# Counter(item) as variable for nth-child css

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply rules using some kind of variable for nth-child purely in CSS? Basically what I am trying to do is to change value for unspecified amount of elements  depending on their position within element. Is there a way to use for example counter-increment or something on that base as variable for child position and value of some property within the element?

Something among those lines (which does not work):

```
.slider{
    counter-reset:item;
}
.slide{
    counter-increment:item;
    color:red;
}
.slide:nth-child(counter(item)){
    line-height:counter(item);
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Basically, no, you can't. Depending on your actual requirements it's possible that one or more nth-child declarations will fill your need.

Comment: You will not be able to do this with vanilla CSS counters as they can only be used with the `content` property. I have no idea if this is doable with Sass or LESS, given that the counters depend on the number of elements on the page and not within the stylesheet.

Comment: I am about to use it for manipulating transition-delay (so the elements slide in in slightly different times). Just wonder if it is possible to simplify the code. I think I will need no more than 10 declarations, yet still it would be nice if there would be some way to simplify the code.

Comment: @Jan Did you find a solution to this? Would be super cool to have.

Comment: @MichaelWolthers well I ended up with more classes and declarations. This seems not to be possible. But would be cool...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to pass argument with .slide:nth-child instead of use  "counter-increment" to initialized counter or reset it.
You can refer "http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp"